# Watir webdriver; window.close is closing entire browser?

Tags: rspec, tabs, watir-webdriver

I am running a test where I copy/paste a link into a *new tab*.  Once I am finished with it, I am looking to close it, then continue running other tests within the spec.  The issue at the moment is that when I use `window.close`, it is closing the entire browser instance, not just that particular window.

 Here is my general code:

```
# Method for the window
def this_window
    page = @browser.window(:title, 'Foobar')
    return page
end

# Helper method for copy/paste in new tab
def copy_paste_in_new_tab
    @browser.send_keys [:command, 't']
    @browser.send_keys [:command, 'v']
    @browser.send_keys [:return]
end

# How it appears in the spec
it 'goes to new page' do
    copy_paste_in_new_tab
    sleep 1
    this_window.use
end
it 'interacts with new window' do
    # runs some tests on new window correctly
end
it 'closes the window' do
    this_window.close
    sleep 2
end
it 'continues to other tests' do
    # by this point the entire session has closed
end
```

This is the error I am getting in the terminal:

```
An error occurred in an `after(:context)` hook.
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 7055
occurred at /Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
```

I am only encountering issues when I try to execute code *after* closing that last window.  If I use `this_window.close` as my last code, then it works correctly 
 Any ideas on what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla does not and will not support interacting with tabs in Firefox.
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3380

Comment: With this in mind, would it be more applicable to automate opening in a new _window_ to run tests?

Comment: Yes, use windows instead of tabs and it should work. :)